# Visual Studio Code - Target URI doesn't exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I am trying to debug a flutter project. The program is throwing error because widget_test.dart is unable to import main.dart

I usually create projects with Intellij. This is the first project I created with Visual Studio Code.

[image]

I am unable to clear this error message

`Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:ipl_test2/main.dart'.`

what is the cause of this error? and how to clear this error?

Comment: could you check your pubspec.yaml ? what's the name of your project? (1st line)

Comment: Ahhh! my bad! the name is different. Thanks a lot @diegoveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the same name of what you describe in your `pubspec.yaml` file, specifically the `name` property.

```
import 'package:change_the_name_here/main.dart';
```